Page refresh at incremental intervals
I have hard-coded if conditions with multiple lines of code to refresh a webpage at every 300th iteration in for loop.
My code is as below
if counter == 300:
    driver.refresh()
    time.sleep(20)
if counter == 600:
    driver.refresh()
    time.sleep(20)
if counter == 900:
    driver.refresh()
    time.sleep(20)
if counter == 1200:
    driver.refresh()
    time.sleep(20)

is there any modification in the above to shorten the if conditions.

All the if-blocks are the same, just different conditions. Do you know how or works?

if value % 300 == 0 ?

if value in (300,600,900,1200)

modulo
Using modulo to execute each 300th iteration:
if counter % 300 == 0:
    driver.refresh()
    time.sleep(20)

